# Representation of Noise in Fourier transform

Tags: discrete-data, fourier-transform, noise

I perform an experiment where I sample $M(k)$ which is in theory related to $|f(x)|^2$ via $M(k)=\int e^{ikx}|f(x)|^2\,dx$. I perform the discrete FT on my data in order to obtain $|f(x)|^2$. Without experimental noise I expect a real positive result, but due to experimental noise I find small but non-zero imaginary parts and small negative real parts. What is the correct way to present the measured $|f(x)|^2$. Should I plot the absolute value of my transformed complex result or should I plot the real part? Can I use the imaginary parts to find error bars on my $|f(x)|^2$ measurement?